# Docker 500 error

Tags: ubuntu, docker

**Edit**: it seems to be a simple pulling or image update problem, since the error vanished after 2 hours and the script now works.

I'm getting a weird error from the Docker registry when building images. Every time I try to build a file I immediately get the error:

```
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:trusty 
HTTP code: 500
```

And that's it. I've always been using these lines in my Dockerfiles without any problem. I first wondered if I could have broken them ie via a typo that Docker would not have indicated in the errot message. But the import also fails with a simple 2 line script:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN mkdir home/aDir
```

I get the same error with from ubuntu:14.04, from ubuntu:12.04, from ubuntu etc.

Any thought? I found no trace of such an error on the web... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Hub Engineer here, sorry for the problems with the 500 error experienced. We ran into some issues this morning and they should be solved now.  If you're still experiencing a problem, feel free to reach out to us directly at `support@docker.com`.

I also wanted to mention that for system outages and problems, you can check https://status.docker.com/ for the latest in status updates.